# Ben & Holly 'Elf Rescue' vs Thunderbirds

Tags: thunderbirds

I was half-dozing while watching Ben & Holly's Little Kingdom (with my grandson) when the king got his vehicle trapped, so he phoned for **Elf Rescue**.

Suddenly I sat up in delight, it transpires Elf Rescue is a parody of **International** **Rescue** and they turned up in their equivalent of Thunderbirds 1&2.

Thunderbird 2 then deployed a pod and it released **The Mole** to dig out the king, however, as the people are tiny elves and fairies, it was a cartoon real mole that came out of the pod, not a machine.

My question is:- Are any other Thunderbird type vehicles ever shown in Ben and Holly? Including their versions of pod machines.

Comment: This is a delightful question

Comment: Just so long as it doesn't cause a jelly flood!

Comment: At 2:36 they missed out on an easy "what are you sinking about?" joke there :(

Comment: A quick shout-out to the man of many voices linking the two shows (and many more): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Graham_(actor)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There are four primary ['Elf Rescue'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6Xqc1iAgT8&feature=youtu.be) vehicles; the **Elf Rocket** (analogous to Thunderbird 1), the **Elf Plane** (analogous to Thunderbird 2), the **Elf Helicopter** and the **Elf Submarine** (analogous to Thunderbird 4). This appears to be the entire complement as the Wise Old Elf states that he is...

> "*...calling **all** Elf Rescue vehicles*".
>
> [image]
> <sub><sup>***Ben & Holly: Elf Rescue***</sup></sub>

---

The **Elf Rocket** has a lowerable claw as well as an on-board flight attendant service (with tea and biscuits). It can also carry the Elf Submarine.

> [image]
>
> [image]

The **Elf Plane**, in addition to being able to carry the submarine, has a droppable pod containing 'The Mole' (a literal mole).

> [image]

The **Elf Helicopter** can drop a retractable sling.

> [image]

The **Elf Submarine** can tow vehicles on the surface.

> [image]

---

**Appearances;**

**Elf Plane**

- "*Snow*" (Season 1, Episode 51 (First appearance))
- "*The North Pole*" (Season 1, Episode 52)
- "*Elf Rescue*" (Season 2, Episode 8) **#**
- "*The Lost City*" (Season 2, Episode 12) **#**
- "*Mr Elf Takes a Holiday*" (Season 2, Episode 25)
- "*Nanny Plum and the Wise Old Elf Swap Jobs for One Whole Day*" (Season 2, Episode 42) **#**
- "*Ben and Holly's Christmas, Part 1*" (Season 2, Episode 51)

**Elf Rocket**

- "*The Elf Rocket*" (Season 1, Episode 44 (First appearance))
- "*Picnic on the Moon*" (Season 1, Episode 45)
- "*Elf Rescue*" (Season 2, Episode 8) **#**
- "*Mr Elf Takes a Holiday*" (Season 2, Episode 25) **#**
- "*Nanny Plum and the Wise Old Elf Swap Jobs for One Whole Day*" (Season 2, Episode 42) **#**

**Elf Submarine**

- "*The Elf Submarine*" (Season 1, Episode 48 (First appearance))
- "*Elf Rescue*" (Season 2, Episode 8) **#**
- "*Mr Elf Takes a Holiday*" (Season 2, Episode 25) **#**
- "*Nanny Plum and the Wise Old Elf Swap Jobs for One Whole Day*" (Season 2, Episode 42) **#**
- "*The Mermaid*" (Season 2, Episode 45)

**Elf Helicopter**

- "*Elf Rescue*" (Season 2, Episode 8 (First Appearance)) **#**
- "*Lucy's School*" (Season 2, Episode 9) **#**
- "*Honey Bees*" (Season 2, Episode 26)
- "*Nanny Plum and the Wise Old Elf Swap Jobs for One Whole Day*" (Season 2, Episode 42) **#**
- "*Ben and Holly's Christmas, Part 2*" (Season 2, Episode 52)

<sub>Those marked with a **#** are episodes in which the vehicles are explicitly stated to be operating as part of Elf Rescue.</sub>

Comment: @M__ - I've said it before. If something's worth doing, it's worth doing ***with colossal overkill***

Comment: @M__ that's how Valorum has amassed well over half a million rep.   By Colosal Overkill.

Comment: Thanks @Criggie I understand a bit more. Nevertheless they must have professional insight, this is not the response of an amateur. If its a question on genetic computation I can respond with equal thoroughness, wanna know about COVID-19 I know it ... but lets be clear, this is Ben and Holly's Little Kingdom.

Comment: @M__ - All of the episodes are freely available on YouTube and the machines themselves are big obvious looking objects. There are 100(ish) episodes and it takes about five to ten seconds to scan through and see if any of the vehicles are in that episode. Total time to review the entire series was less than 10-15 minutes, which I did while watching TV on the other channel.

Comment: _Prophecies another name change: **Valorum** -> **Captain Colossal Overkill**_